# Showing a coloring for a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How would I do A,B,and C fo the following graph.[image]

A. For A I used the greedy algorith.
So I did $v_1=1,v_2=1,v_3=1,v_4=1,v_5=2,v_6=2,v_7=3,v_8=4$

So I got that the chromatic coloring is 4.

C. For C I said no because we know for every graph G  the chromatic number will always be less than or equal to 1 plus the the largest degree in the graph and $1+\Delta=4$ so there cannot be a coloring with more than four colors using greedy.

B. I think there is a different ordering using different ordering that uses fewer color but I canot find it.

Comment: the problem with the ordering is, that for node $v_8$, all three nodes around it already are coloured in a different colour. Try to find an ordering where this does not happen

Comment: you should be able to get an ordering using only 2 colours (as this is a tree)

Comment: your answers to a and c look good for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuition says if you do it bad then do it conversely. :-) The greedy algorithm directed by the inverse order $v_8,\dots, v_1$ produces a two-color coloring.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you